# object inside iframe not recognizable by selenium webdriver

Tags: iframe, webdriver

I wrote a code for switching into frame and send some values to a text box. when writing the code it worked for me. now it is now recognising the  object and it is not passing the value. please let me know why it is failing.

Getobject method finds the element using xpath, xpath are stored in property file.

```
getobject("ForgotClaimNumber_Link").click();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("fancybox-frame")));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,100);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtClaimNum']")));
getobject("ClaimNumber_Edit").sendKeys("5200098863");
getobject("Find_Button").click();
```

Comment: getobject("ClaimNumber_Edit").sendKeys("5200098863");
getobject("Find_Button").click(); _"ClaimNumber_Edit"_ and _"Find_Button"_ don't exactly look like Xpaths. Have you tried with good old **driver.findElementBy**??

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to switch to the frame first then you can send other commands to it. Dont think you can switch to a frame and then use the find element in one command. you will need to know the frame name or id. Once you know that you can perform actions. when your done with the frame you need to go back to the main window (exit frame)

driver.switchTo().frame("put ID or Name here");
driver.findElement(By.id("ID"));